# Dealing with NAs in Bayesian models

Tags: r, na, bayesian, stan, rstan

I made a certain Bayesian model, including the typical components (data, model, parameters, likelihood).

This model is a linear regression:

```
library(ggplot2)
#library (ggedit)
library(plyr)
library(StanHeaders)
library(rstan)

# Equation (1)

for(i in 1:N){
    alphaC_P[i] ~ normal ((alphaC_A[Date[i]]) * (1- (F_T[Date[i]])) +
                            alphaC_T[i] * (F_T[Date[i]]), sigma_C);
    }
```

Due to memory needs, I am running this analysis on a cluster.
I prepare the list of elements (e.g., `#Equation (2):   mylist <- list()`)

Finally, I run the Bayesian analysis on the cluster.

```
Equation (3)

rstan::stan(file=args[2], data= mylist, cores=12, warmup= 48000, 
                          iter= 50000, chains= 4, seed = 14)

# file=args[2] = Bayesian model
```

Since my data has NAs, my question is:
Where should I include the instruction to omit/ignore/exclude the NAs?
e.g., should it be in Equation #1, #2 or #3?

Finally, what should I do: omit, ignore, exclude them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code example is not very clear. For example, in your first code snippet, you're mixing R with Stan syntax.

From a Stan perspective it's very simple: Stan does not accept `NA`s in data. You can do two things:

- Either change `NA`s to some arbitrary number and then have your Stan model check for the presence of this magic number in your data and deal with it in a suitable way (i.e. remove, ignore, replace, impute),
- Or deal with `NA`s at the R level (i.e. remove, replace, impute) before sending data to the Stan model.

As to *how* to deal with `NA`s, that really depends on your data and data collection process, which only you know the details of (in other words, this needs domain-specific knowledge).

Lastly, a lot of operations in Stan are vectorised. So instead of writing e.g.

```
for (i in 1:N)
    y[i] ~ normal(mu[i], sigma)
```

you can (and should) write

```
y ~ normal(mu, sigma)
```